# SQL Query for Last Names with Apostrophes

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a database of last names, first names, addresses, etc.

I am trying to search by last name, and I have no problem with escapting apostrophes, for example, the data in the table is "O'Malley" and if I search for "O'Malley" I get the intended results.

However, I would also like to be able to search for "omalley" and still return the "O'Malley" record from the table.  Is there any way to ignore the apostrophe in the table?

Or, is my only other option to create a last name field that is stripped of the apostrophe, and then use and OR statement to check both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably check against the `REPLACE('''','',column_name)` value and save yourself an additional "indexable" column.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean  ... Because the table HAS the apostrophe, and potentially the search term would not, so I can't strip it from the search term.

Comment: SELECT desired_columns FROM table WHERE last_name='<search_term>' OR REPLACE('''','',last_name)='<search_term>'
Not sure how you're comparing (exact or partial) but that should give you the idea. Although you could also do a string replace on the search term and make the apostraphe a % and use the LIKE comparer.

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM meminfo WHERE LOWER(REPLACE('''','',lname)) = 'omalley'";

This is not returning any results.  Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @Brian, I think the arguments are in the wrong order - it should probably be `$query = "SELECT * FROM meminfo WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(lname,'''','')) = 'omalley'"`

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * -- replace with appropriate field list
FROM MyTable
WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(column_name,'''','')) = 'omalley'
```

EDIT - Corrected REPLACE syntax

Comment: Bannister : set column to ci ?

Comment: @ajreal: Please can you clarify your comment?

Comment: This seems like the best answer to me.

Comment: `lower` is not necessary if the column collate is xxx_ci unless u want to explicitly make it as cs

Comment: @ajreal: I see what you mean - my assumption was that cs was both default and desired (in general) on the table, but for this particular query (and probably some others), cs was not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports SOUNDEX - you could searh on names that "sound" like omalley.  Soundex is really helpful when you want to try and find people quick and not have to ask how to spell something...[More about Soundex](http://databases.about.com/od/development/l/aasoundex.htm)

For example the name I have seen Thomas spelled Tomas, Tomes, Tomus  - even though all spelled differntly, soundex will find it  - cause they all "sound the same".  Especially nowadays when people are looking for different ways to spell common names, this can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all instances of `'` with `'?` and use `REGEXP`.

```
SELECT *
  FROM person
 WHERE name REGEXP 'o\'?malley'
```

If you're not familiar with `?` in regex, it means "this character can appear here, but it doesn't have to." For example, `colou?r` would match both "color" and "colour".

Note: This solution works in MySQL but I don't know what DBMS you're using.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm not sure that this is an answer to the question you asked.